# Why is const (<=5) 5 6 == False?

Tags: haskell

Can you please break down how the Haskell expression

`const (<=5) 5 6`

evaluates to `False` ?

What is this expression made of? Looking at the [definition](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/const_f.html) of `const` didn't help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**`const :: a -> b -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:const) is a function that takes two values. It *ignores* the second value, and returns then the first one. It thus can be implemented for example as:

```
const :: a -> b -> a
const x _ = x
```

If you write `const (<=5) 5 6`, then this is short for `((const (<= 5) 5) 6`. So it means that `(<= 5)` is the value for `x`, and `5` is the value we *ignore*.

This thus means that `const (<= 5) 5` is equivalent to `(<= 5)`. We then apply `6` to the function `(<= 5)`. The `(<= 5)` is an [*operator sectioning of an infix operator*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator), it is thus equivalent to `\x -> (<=) x 5`. If we thus evaluate `(<= 5) 6`, we evaluate `(\x -> (<=) x 5) 6`, or `(<=) 6 5`. We thus check if `6` is less than or equal to `5`, and this is not the case, so we return `False`.

Answer (score 3):

Because of currying, `const (<=5) 5 6` is equivalent to this:

```
(((const) (<=5)) 5) 6 -- yes, that's a lot of parentheses
```

Or, in other words:

```
const_le_5 = const (<=5)
const_le_5_apply_to_5 = const_le_5 5
final_result = const_le_5_apply_to_5 6
```

BUT we see from the definition of `const` that it simply evaluates to its *first* argument, which is `(<=5)` in this case, so we get this:

1. `const_le_5_apply_to_5` is the same as `const (<=5) 5`
2. ...which is, by the definition of `const`, the same as `(<=5)`

Because `const_le_5_apply_to_5` evaluated to `(<=5)`, `final_result` actually is the same as `(<=5) 6`, which is false since 6 is *not* less than or equal to 5.